# How do I add a jar file to import the class?

Tags: java, import, jar

I downloaded json-20200518.jar (from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20200518), and put it in my bin folder (the same folder where I have javac.exe) which is added to my PATH variable.

My client.java file has:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

In cmd, I run:

```
javac -cp json-20200518.jar client.java
```

And I get this error:

```
client.java:3: error: package org.json.simple does not exist
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

What do I have to do with the jar file to make it work?

Comment: Wrong class path. Try with javac -cp . client.java

Comment: I get the same error with javac -cp json-20200518.jar client.java

Comment: Are you running  javac command from different location than bin folder

Comment: @Ansu I tried running it from the bin folder and it gives the same error

Comment: @Gimmethe411 use package name as org.json.JSONObject and not org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: @Ansu Great, thanks

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Added the same in answer to help others, please help me to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specified maven jar file link, the package structure for `JSONObject` class is `org.json.JSONObject`.

Try to change the package name from `org.json.simple.JSONObject` to `org.json.JSONObject` and it will compile successfully.